# How to splice a string to uneven parts in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that has autocomplete on it (custom made autocomplete).

When the user types a word, the matching phrase should appear but the word the user typed should have a different color.

So if for example I have the string like **"Hello World"** and the user types **"ll"**, He should get a list of matching phrases that contain **"ll"** but the **"ll"** should have different color.

So i need a way to splice "Hello World" so i'll get : `["he","ll","o World"]` and then i can wrap **"ll"** with `<span>` and style it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use replace

```
strhtml.replace (/yourstrToSearch/g, '<span class="cl">' + 'yourstrToSearch' + '</span >');
```

**Edit:**

```
yourstrToSearch = "ll";
var regex = new RegExp( yourstrToSearch, "gi");
$('#div1').html($('#div1').html().replace(regex, '<span class="cl">' + yourstrToSearch + '</span >'));
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/YWrxY/2/)**

Answer (score 3):

One possible regex solution:

```
var part = "ll";
"Hello World".match(new RegExp("^(.*)(" + part + ")(.*)$")).slice(1);
// >> ["He", "ll", "o World"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget about splitting the string. In this case it's much easier to replace match (**ll** in your example) with *span* like so:

```
'Hello World'.replace(/(ll)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Or even better, if you'd like for each **ll** in text to have different styles you can pass function to replace function like so:

```
var i = 0;
'Hello Hello World'.replace(/(ll)/g, function(match) {
    i++;
    return '<span class="highlight-'+i+'">'+match+'</span>;
});

// above returns - you can style highlight-1 .. n so each of them have different color
'He<span class="highlight-1">ll</span>o He<span class="highlight-2">ll</span>o World'
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is *not* to use regular expressions because they're going to fail if the replacement string contains a regex special character, like a dot or braces. Therefore, just pass the string as is to `replace`:

```
str = 'Hello Hello World'
sub = 'll'
result = str.replace(sub, '<span>$&</span>')
```

Note that this replaces only the first occurrence of `sub` if there are many, but that's probably how you want it.